# Can we modify existing library capsule?

Tags: bixby

Specifically, I want to check certain cities in the geo library capsule. We are doing a city-based search by having our system call an API.

What we want to accomplish at the end is make sure users can do searches in cities where we have available listings and prevent them from fruitlessly searching in places we do not cover. A big part of this is restricting the cities that we will do a search in, so I’m hoping we can restrict what the geo library will recognize. The other part is that we would like to dynamically have some disambiguation state prompt based on cities we support if the city name could mean multiple states.

So TLDR: there any way to customize the built in library capsules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't need to make any customizations to the geo library capsule.

You would simply need to have your Action take the user's location and add logic to check it against your location requirements before deciding whether or not you cover the places relevant to the particular user and serving the appropriate output to the user.

Adding code to explain comment:

Action 1 model:

```
action (Action1) {
  description (Checks to see if initial input can be served)
  type (Search)
  collect {
    input (initialInput) {
      type (InitialInput)
      min (Required) max (One)
    }
  }

  output (VerifiedInput)
}
```

Action 2 model:

```
action (Action2) {
  description (Does the search)
  type (Search)
  collect {
    input (verifiedInput) {
      type (VerifiedInput)
      min (Required) max (One)
      default-init {
        intent {
          goal:Action1
        }
      }
    }
    input (searchParameters) {
      type (SearchParameters)
      min (Required) max (Many)
    }
  }

  output (FinalOutput)
}
```

You would train utterances to have the goal of `Action2` and, since the `default-init` for one of its inputs requires `Action1` to be launched, Bixby will go through `Action1` first and then go through `Action2`.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Say we prompt for a city/state, we would then want to call an api and check if that area is available, and then if so, ask for more search refinements before doing the search. I don't think we can keep track of state between things the user says, so is there a way to do this location check before prompting for more search parameters?

Comment: No worries! I added some more information to my answer to address the initial check you want to make before asking for search parameters. Hope it helps!